# Accessing RESTfull Web service in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, rest, restkit

I am trying to learn some things regarding RestKit framework for iOS applications. It provides for a more easy way to communicate with a RESTfull web service, plus it reduces boiler-plate code. There are about 6 core features regarding the framework. I am wondering what are the alternative way(s) to communicate with a RESTfull web service? Can you give me an example; more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [an informative tutorial](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/tutorial-simple-iphone-rest-client) which describes in detail how to create a simple REST client complete with examples.  It touches on some fundamental concepts such as *Asynchronous* and *Synchronous* requests using [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as well as parsing the response using [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact I would be grateful if you could give me a summary of some essential steps perfuming that sort of communication. I am not trying to implement it, I just need an overview. I only need a summary, at this stage I don't have time to get into detailed tutorial.

Comment: Essentially you make a request to the server using `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest`.  Server returns a response via a delegate method of the connection, which you will then feed into your `NSXMLParser` in order to parse and do what you wish to the data.  That's the gist of it.  You'll have to look at apple docs or the tutorial if you need to know what this looks like or how to do it, or the general specifics of the aforementioned objects.

Comment: Thanks, this is all I needed to know at this stage. Now I have some sort of understanding of complexity if any.